# If $L^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$ then $L^{-1}(y+U)=\emptyset$ where $L$ linear and $U$ subspace and $y+U$ is an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have tried a contradiction proof assuming there exists a $x$ such that $L(x)=y+u$ where $u\in U $.  But I cannot prove that $ u$ is necessarily in $L^{-1}(U)$

Comment: Could you add more context? The question is confusing as is. I'm guessing that $L^{-1}(y)$ is the inverse image of $\{y\}$ under $L$? Taking $U = \operatorname{span}\{y\}$ means that $0 \in L^{-1}(y + U)$.

Comment: Are there some additional assumptions on $U$ or $L$? If you take the whole vectorspace as the subspace $U$, the statement is obviously false.

Comment: @TheoBendit $L$ is a linear map $V \rightarrow W$ , $y$ is an element of $W$, $U$ is an arbitrary subspace of $W$. $L^{-1}(y)$ is the set of all elements in $V$ such that if $x\in L^{-1}(y)$ then $L(x) =y$. Is the above statement true?

Comment: @maxmilgram $y+U$ is an affine subspace. So it cannot be the whole vector space

Comment: As I said, take $U=W$. The statement now claims that $L^{-1}(W)$ is empty.

Comment: @maxmilgram $U$ must be a subspace such that $y+U$ is an affine subspace. I.e. $y+U\neq U$

Comment: It's still wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is false, as posed. One can build a counterexample as follows:

Take arbitrary vector spaces $V, W$ over the same field, with $W$ non-trivial. Let $L$ be the $0$ map, and $y \in W \setminus \{0\}$. Then $L^{-1}\{y\} = \emptyset$, as $L(x) = 0 \neq y$ for all $x$.

Further, let $U = \operatorname{span}\{y\}$. Then $0 = y + (-1)y \in y + U$, hence
$$V = L^{-1}\{0\} \subseteq L^{-1}(y + U) \subseteq V,$$
hence $L^{-1}(y + U) = V \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I assume $y+U$ to be an affine subspace. Does this change the outcome?

Comment: @New2Math Nope. An affine subspace is a set in the form $y + U$, where $y$ is a point and $U$ is a subspace, so the question has not changed. Also, to address a previous comment, every vector space is an affine subspace of itself, i.e. affine subspaces do not need to be proper subsets. That said, my $U$ is a line, which could easily be made to be a proper affine subspace, simply by making sure $W$ is at least dimension $2$.

Comment: The reason of my question is that in my lecture notes there is the claim that for all $a\in L^{-1}\{y\}:L^{-1}(y+U) = a + L^{-1}(U)$ but if $L^{-1} (y) $ is empty the right side is always empty, correct? But you said the left side is not necessarily empty, so the statement is false? Where is my missunderstanding?

Comment: The statement in your lecture notes still holds: In your case there simply is no such $a$. Thus it holds true that for all applicable $a$. Another example. Is the following statement true? "All integers that are both even and uneven are prime."

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary $z\in W$ take $U=\mbox{span}\{z-y\}$. Now your statement claims that $L^{-1}(z)$ is empty.

Since we started with an arbitrary $z$ the statement is obviously false.